# SignalR- send data to a specific client

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

I want to send data to a specific client. to do that I am trying with the following;

```
public Task GetWaitingOrdersCount(string id, string clientId)
    {
        DateTime today = Util.getCurrentDateTime();

      var data = 10

      return Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).loadOrders(data);

      //return data;
    }
```

In the above code, I want to send 'data' to the 'clientId' passed to this method.
BUT I m having an error in this line

```
 return Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).loadOrders(data);
```

And the error is

```
'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<object>' does not contain a definition for 'loadOrders'
```

the client side code

```
con.loadOrders = function (data) {
        loadOrders(data);

    };

function loadOrders(data) {

    $('#totalOrders').html(data);
}
```

Any help about the error???

**EDIT:**
This is my full client code..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var con;
$(document).ready(function () {
    con = $.connection.messagingHub;


    $.connection.hub.start(function () {
        var myClientId = $.connection.hub.id;
        con.getWaitingOrdersCount('<%:ViewBag.rid%>',myClientId).done(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    });

    con.client.loadOrders = function (data) {
        loadOrders(data);

    };

});
function loadOrders(data) {

    $('#totalOrders').html(data);
```

Comment: what is the return type of loadOrders(data) ?

Comment: i am not returning anything..just printing the 'data' in inside a <a> tag.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how the returned Task from GetWaitingOrdersCount is used?

Comment: How is `Clients.Client` defined and what is it?

Comment: i added full client side code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried out your code (slightly modified) and it works fine for me.  What version of SignalR are you using?  Judging by your server code I'd say 1.0Alpha1+ but your client code looks more like 0.5.3, that is unless your con object is assigned to $.connection.yourhub.client;

If you update to SignalR 1.0Alpha2 and change your client code to be:

```
var con = $.connection.myCon;// This is arbitrary and would change based on your naming

con.client.loadOrders = function (data) {
    loadOrders(data);

};

function loadOrders(data) {
    $('#totalOrders').html(data);
}
```

That being said I believe your issue has to do with the version of SignalR you are using, server side that is: since you're receiving a task oriented error.  Another piece of information that might be beneficial would be to know how GetWaitingOrdersCount is being called.  Aka is it being invoked from the client directly via: con.server.getWaitingOrdersCount or is it being called from within the hub.

Hope this info helps!

Comment: Hi Taylor..my signalR version is 0.5.1.10822. Is this the right version i am working with?? i added full client code in my question, i also modified according to your code. Still having the problem :(

Comment: Oh geez, if you're using 0.5.1 then your Clients.Client piece is wrong.  The correct code in 0.5.1 is Clients[Context.ConnectionId].loadOrders(data);.  If you want to update to 1.0 Alpha2 you can search Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR in Nuget and set your filter to "Include Pre-release".  Then just update from there.  Keep in mind if using 1.0 Alpha 2 there are several breaking changes (But I'd strongly recommend using 1.0 Alpha2).

Comment: ok..i upgraded to alpha2. the task error is gone now. but end up having another problem. here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13512566/can-not-debug-my-hub-method-after-upgrading-to-signalr-1-alpha2